# How can I declare the correct content to import another swiftui file into the contentview file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

I'm a bit new to swift and am a bit confused about what is being asked of me. Some background: I found a guy online who has created a swiftui file for a sliding bottom view bar and I wanted to implement it into my ContentView swiftui file. I have looked up and down the internet and tried to play around with things after clicking "fix" in xcode but I have had no luck.

Here are images of the error, me clicking "fix" prompt from xcode, and the BottomSheetView.swift file's code -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufNdQ.jpg

Can someone help me by explaining what exactly swift is asking me to do and let me know how I can solve this error?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
        VStack{
            MapView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            let heightDouble = CGFloat(150.00)

            BottomSheetView(isOpen: .constant(true), maxHeight: heightDouble, content: <#() -> Content#>)


        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors in SwiftUI are not always shown where they really are. The problem in your code snippet is at the line:

```swift
let heightDouble = CGFloat(150.00)
```

and it should be: *Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'*

Try this and you'll see, that the problem is not in other views:

```swift
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            VStack{
                Text("hello") // replaced MapView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                // you need to delete this row to avoid error
                let heightDouble = CGFloat(150.00)

                Text("world") // replaced BottomSheetView(...)

            }
        }
    }
```

the code in `body` variable must return `some View`, but defining a constant inside it violates this rule

**update**
in `BottomSheetView` you have `content` which is other `View`. I don't see all the code, but I think it should be something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isOpen = true
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
        VStack{
            MapView()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            BottomSheetView(isOpen: self.$isOpen, maxHeight: CGFLoat(150)) {
                Text("bottom")
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code from above is all of my code for the whole file. I added these changes and have now gotten more errors. please see here https://imgur.com/a/PIHU0U1

Comment: also, https://imgur.com/a/GqEjMzo here is the code from the file im importing

Comment: @IsaiahThomas, oh, I think I mistyped in ```CGFloat(150)```, maybe there is russian 'C', try to copy-paste this: CGFloat(150) or just leave ```150``` or ```150.0``` there, swift will understand

Comment: @IsaiahThomas did it help?

Comment: yes!!! this fixed my issue. thanks a bunch! now my only problem is i cant add .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom) to this. i get an error. any ideas?

Comment: @IsaiahThomas where do you want to add ```.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)```?

Comment: I have figured it out, thanks! I was putting it in between the {} lol. I appreciate your help!